# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method String.Format

Tags: c#, string, entity-framework, linq, formatting

I'm trying to format a double value (by showing only 2 decimals). I tried to use AsEnumerable but I keep getting this error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   String.Format

```
var tw = workers.Select(x => new
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                JobOpportunityFeedbacks = x.JobOpportunityFeedbacks.AsEnumerable().
                Select(y => new
                {
                    Rating = String.Format("0.00",y.Rating),
                    Feedback = y.Feedback
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the `AsEnumerable` outside of your initial `Select`

```
var tw = workers.Select(x => new
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        JobOpportunityFeedbacks = x.JobOpportunityFeedbacks
            .Select(y => new
            {
                y.Rating,
                y.Feedback
            })
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        x.Id,
        JopOpertunityFeedbacks = x.JobOpportunityFeedbacks
            .Select(y => new
            {
                Rating = String.Format("0.00",y.Rating),
                y.Feedback
            })
    });
```

Comment: You're answer is the solution. However, it's going to be twice slower, do you think there is another alternative. (I can't use decimal type unfortunately)

Comment: @HediNaily What do you mean twice as slow?  Twice as slow as what?  I know it looks like you're doing the same stuff twice, but this avoids having the DB return more data than you need.

Answer (score 0):

Use SqlFunctions class - I didn't try this but should work.

```
var tw = workers.Select(x => new
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                JobOpportunityFeedbacks = x.JobOpportunityFeedbacks.AsEnumerable().
                Select(y => new
                {
                    Rating = SqlFunctions.StringConvert(y.Rating, 4, 2)
                    Feedback = y.Feedback
                });
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487158(v=vs.110).aspx